# What does this conversation mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Here is the context:

> Trevor: We've had a villa there for quite a few years. It has come in very handy during the summer holidays. I really look forward to going. I love the way the Spanish make a fuss of my kids. They all come over as such warm friendly people.
>
> Stephen: Yes, it's true. The only problem for me is that I can't cope with the heat. Last time I went to Spain, it was so hot that I fainted. It took me quite a bit of time to come round. My wife was anxious. ***She said a bomb could have gone off, and I wouldn't have come to.***
>
> Trevor: Really?......

I just don't understand the sentence in bold text.

Answer (score 2):

> to come to, to come round

To regain consciousness after fainting.

> to go off

To explode

So his wife said that a bomb could have exploded and he wouldn't have regained consciousness (despite the loud bang). Clearly his wife exaggerated the extent of his fainting spell :)